# cant install rails in ubuntu 9.10 in my eee pc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

i am trying to install rails in my eee pc with the last version of ubuntu and i have some package that are told installable.how is it possible?i can even install gem

```
fenec@fenec-laptop:~$ gem
The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages:
 * rubygems1.8
 * rubygems1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
gem: command not found


root@fenec-laptop:/home/fenec# apt-get install rubygems1.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package rubygems1.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package rubygems1.8 has no installation candidate
```

Is it possible that some package are not installable due to my hardware? I have this problem only with this version of ubuntu i used to have ubuntu 8.10 and rails was working like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually install ruby gems from source. I would try following [this guide](http://www.hackido.com/2009/04/install-ruby-rails-on-ubuntu-904-jaunty.html) - it's worked for me on multiple different Ubuntu installs.

Comment: I've always had a much better experience installing RubyGems from source. The apt one is almost always behind version-wise and it is common that a gem will need the latest version of RG.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails